# run global installed npm programs with npm

Tags: node.js, npm

So you have `npm bin -g` that yields the bin directory where npm installs stuff. Is there a way to use npm to run stuff from that directory? An obvious option would be `$(npm bin -g)/installednodeprogram` but I am calling this from an external program (emacs) and would like to avoid bringing up a shell. Also I could get the path from `npm bin -g` and then concatenate the program name and do all sorts of checks but I hope there is a cleaner way I couldn't find like `npm run-binary installednodeprogram`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've installed a program globally, you can run its command from the shell just like any other. In fact, that's what the `npm` command itself is.

For example:

```
npm install -g browserify
browserify file.js # browserify command is now available
```

Comment: Yeah I was trying to have emacs install and run swank-js but I wanted to do everything via npm in order for it to work with any `.npmrc`. Turns out I am stuck with doing the two-step thing. (obtaining the path with `npm bin -g` and then running the file from there)