# Global npm dependency express won't run

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

So I have been using npm for some time and have done a recent reinstall from win8.1 to win8.1. I know it worked before and it says so [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25998260/run-global-installed-npm-programs-with-npm) as well.

Since then I have installed `npm i -g express` but it won't run.

> 'express' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I tried running express from console and it won't run.

This is in my path: `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm`

Comment: when you run `npm ls -g --depth=0`, what is the path that shows up at the top of the output?  Is *that* path in your `PATH`?

Comment: C:\Users\Dito\AppData\Roaming\npm
└── express@4.10.4

Comment: It is but when i type npm bin -g it says it isn't

Comment: So the path for `-g` is in your `PATH`?  If so...you might try to uninstall, clean the cache, and reinstall.  It's not satisfying advice, but it has worked for me in the past in weird situations like this.

Comment: still doesnt work after reinstall and restart :/

Comment: npm install -g express-generator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CLI is **express-generator**.

Do `npm install -g express-generator`.

Comment: TY man! I even recall doing this some time ago but on the blog I was reading the guy said install express and I totally forgot